# Separating objects from JSON Shell command

Tags: json, shell

I have a JSON array as follows.

```
[ { "release": "2008.1006", "kernel": "2.6.32-754.3.5", "os": "6.10", "current": true }, { "release": "2008.1006", "kernel": "3.10.0-862.14.4", "os": "7.5", "current": true } ]
```

When I print the array length using `${#array[@]}`, it gives me 1. I want an array containing the objects present in this array using a shell script .

I want an array of the objects under curly braces. Tried many hacks but I did not get any desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s='[ { "release": "2008.1006", "kernel": "2.6.32-754.3.5", "os": "6.10", "current": true }, { "release": "2008.1006", "kernel": "3.10.0-862.14.4", "os": "7.5", "current": true } ]'
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a items < <(jq -c '.[]' <<<"$s" && printf '\0')

echo "Number of items: ${#items[@]}"
(( ${#items[@]} )) && printf ' - %s\n' "${items[@]}"
```

...properly emits:

```
Number of items: 2
 - {"release":"2008.1006","kernel":"2.6.32-754.3.5","os":"6.10","current":true}
 - {"release":"2008.1006","kernel":"3.10.0-862.14.4","os":"7.5","current":true}
```

---

If only supporting bash 4.0 or newer, you can swap out `read -a` for `readarray -t` (though this no longer passes through unsuccessful exit status should the `jq` invocation fail):

```
readarray -t items <<<"$(jq -c '.[]' <<<"$s")"
```

Comment: Thanks!!. I already found a way. We can also do it using ---jq '.[index]'-- . The only problem I was facing here is that I was not able to fetch each element of the json array using variable as index in jq. $VaribaleName was not working.  Thanks Again!!

Comment: As a thing to keep in mind -- calling a new copy of `jq` every time you want to index into the data is considerably less efficient than invoking `jq` just once to process the entire contents. (Given a description of your larger goal, an answer that implements *all* the logic in `jq` could potentially be feasible).